# Can Ember handle multiple routes to a single resource?

Tags: ember.js

I want to show the profile page on my web app either by `username` or `user_id`. I've tried the following with no success, any ideas?

```
MyApplication.Router.map(function () {

    this.resource('user', { path: '/user' }, function () {
        this.resource('profile', {path: '/profile/id/:user_id'});
        this.resource('profile', {path: '/profile/:user_username'});
    });

    this.resource('notFound', {path: '/notfound'});
});
```

Comment: Samael could you please choose an answer or answer this yourself? Seeking closure :)

Answer (score 2):

You can merge those two resources into one as follows:

```
MyApplication.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('user', { path: '/user' }, function () {
    this.resource('profile', {path: '/profile/id/:value'});
  });
});

MyApplication.ProfileRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    var value = params.value;
    if (isNaN(value)) {
      return this.store.find('user', { username: value });
    } else {
      return this.store.find('user', value);
    }
  }
});
```

If the `value` in the URL is a number it will do a `findById`; otherwise it will do a `findQuery`. Obviously this approach will fail if some username is a number.

Comment: This `.find('user', {username:value})` looks promising and I've seen other posts on stackoverflow using it but I can't seem to get it to find my user based on username. 

The documentation states that find is just to retrieve a model based on its unique id.
http://emberjs.com/guides/models/finding-a-record/

Comment: @samael the `find` method will call `findQuery` of your adapter if the passed parameter is an object. As I write in my answer: If the value in the URL is a number it will do a findById; otherwise it will do a findQuery.

Answer (score 2):

It seems Ember shouldn't really be used in this way. I've read through issues [551](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/551) and [571](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/571) on [Embers Github](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues). I think it's best to stick with showing a user by id to avoid working against the framework.

Answer (score 0):

If the `URL` is the important part for you, you could change the resource names and keep the url prefix the same, for example:

```
MyApplication.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('user', { path: '/user' }, function () {
    this.resource('profileByUserId', {path: '/profile/id/:user_id'});
    this.resource('profileByUsername', {path: '/profile/:user_username'});
  });
  this.resource('notFound', {path: '/notfound'});
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

May be with nested routes for the profile resource

```
MyApplication.Router.map(function () {

    this.resource('user', { path: '/user' }, function () {
        this.resource('profile', function(){
            this.route('byid',{path: '/id/:user_id'});
            this.route('byname',{path: '/name/:user_username'});
        });
    });

    this.resource('notFound', {path: '/notfound'});
});
```

But remember to implement serialize for the definition of the route with user_name 
http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/

The previos aproach is also valid IMHO